# Youtube video on click not closing after I hit close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a video that I want to show to users on the website, I created a button where they click and it shows a youtube video in popup, but when I close it, it still shows "Playing audio" in the tab and you can hear the video still. How can I achieve when they click X or anywhere else(they can closing it too by clicking anywhere) to actually stops the video and its audio.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
type:'inline',
midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
  });         
});
```

```css
   

 #headerPopup{
  width:75%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#headerPopup iframe{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;

}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank" class="btn btn-white btn-outline-white px-4 py-3 popup-modal"><span class="icon-play mr-2"></span>Watch Video</a></p>

      <div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qN3OueBm9F4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
```

Any help will mean a lot, thanks!

Comment: Do you have the code of your popup ? It's an iframe i believe?

Comment: i dont know why its not working here, in my browsers its playing the video and here in code snipper it doesnt

Comment: When you open your modal, it creates the iframe but there's nothing to destroy it when you close it. What i think is happening is that, when you load the page, the iframe is loaded in the dom, when you open your modal, it starts the video and when you close the modal, it is still present in the DOM but with the play option on. You should have a function that resets your modal when you close it. You can do that just by setting the html of the modal to what it was before or by destroying it and instead of having the iframe static you can generate it on the fly.

Comment: Hmm, can you please help me with that?

Comment: You could try to empty the iframe source on the close event, like `$('iframe').attr('src', '');`

Comment: @BobVandevliet Can you do it in a code please, what should I put inside src? a video link

Comment: I just checked the documentation of magnific popup, it seems that by default, magnific popup handle it quite well, you just have to change the type to "iframe", tell me if that works. 
You can see the doc in this page : https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html
If it doesn't work we'll find another solution with vanilla js or jquery. Let's try and make it work with the framework as it seems to be handled quite well.

Comment: You also have to be careful, there's a small configuration to do for iframes. It is written in the doc i sent in the previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

What if you use the `iframe` content type of the MagnificPopup plugin?
So it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe',
    midClick: true,
    items: {
      // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
      markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">' +
        '<div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">' +
        '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay;     encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
        '</div>',
      patterns: {
        youtube: {
          // URL that will be set as a source for iframe.
          src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/qN3OueBm9F4?autoplay=1'
        }
      },
      // Templating object key. First part defines CSS selector, second attribute.
      // "iframe_src" means: find "iframe" and set attribute "src".
      srcAction: 'iframe_src',
    }
  });
});
```

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe-type

Or try to clear the iframe source using your original Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true,
    callbacks: {
      open: function () {
        // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
        // this - is Magnific Popup object
      },
      close: function () {
        // Will fire when popup is closed
        $('#headerPopup > iframe').attr('src', '');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I replaced my jquery code with yours and it doesnt open the video at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I must say I don't have experience with this plugin and I didn't test it, I just checked the docs. Maybe try to tweak some of the properties. E.g. `src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/qN3OueBm9F4'` instead, as written in the docs?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the iframe source? Example added to my answer.